# MFMailComposeViewController Not Editable in iOS 8 Xcode 6

Tags: ios, swift

I am using the following code to show the email sheet. The sheet shows up but I cannot edit the subject, body. I cannot even press the cancel or send buttons. Here is my implementation:

```
class PeopleListTableViewController: UITableViewController,SWTableViewCellDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate,MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, NSXMLParserDelegate {

 func showEmailSheet(person :Person) {

        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {

            let mailViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
            mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self

            mailViewController.setToRecipients([person.email!])

            self.presentViewController(mailViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Test it on real device with email account being set.

Comment: yes, I am testing on a real physical device.

Comment: Your code works for me. With a small edit mailViewController.setToRecipients(["abc@gmail.com"])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the working code from one of my projects.  Be sure to work with the form on an iOS device and not in the simulator.

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
    @IBAction func launchEmail(sender: AnyObject) {

        var emailTitle = "Feedback"
        var messageBody = "Feature request or bug report?"
        var toRecipents = ["youraddress@gmail.com"]
        var mc: MFMailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mc.mailComposeDelegate = self
        mc.setSubject(emailTitle)
        mc.setMessageBody(messageBody, isHTML: false)
        mc.setToRecipients(toRecipents)

        self.presentViewController(mc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func mailComposeController(controller:MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result:MFMailComposeResult, error:NSError) {
        switch result.value {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled.value:
            println("Mail cancelled")
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved.value:
            println("Mail saved")
        case MFMailComposeResultSent.value:
            println("Mail sent")
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed.value:
            println("Mail sent failure: %@", [error.localizedDescription])
        default:
            break
        }
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: I used your code and still I cannot edit anything in the email form sheet. It is frozen. I see bunch of auto layout errors in the console.

Comment: did you this to your class MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate and import MessageUI

Comment: yes I am using the MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate as indicated in the original question.

Comment: one more thing, doesn't work in simulator, must do on a phone

Comment: Yes I am using a real device!

Comment: XCODE 6.0.1, tested on an iPhone %s using iOS 7.1.  I updated the code with my full code.  I pasted into a blank project, hooked up one button and ran it.  Works.  Will test an iOS8 device next.

Comment: Mystery to me! Mine is frozen, I cannot even close the mail compose window!

Comment: Try disable auto layout.

Comment: Ok, tested on iOS8.  Works.  Per @CarouselMin, I have auto layout off.  (it was never on)

Comment: I turned off auto layout but still on the console it says broken constraints. Xcode 6.1 is seriously messed up and extremely buggy!

Comment: did you run a blank project with just the mail code and 1 button?

Comment: i don't think it is auto layouts.  If a blank project works with this code, then there is something else.  If you get frustrated and are willing to post to github I can look at it.

Comment: I created a new project and yes it works on that one! The weird thing is that I copy pasted my own code and it works fine. Maybe auto layout has something to do with it.

Comment: Looks like it required a restart! Now it seems to be working fine on the device.

Comment: Awesome!  I know what wasting 8 hours with problems like this feels like.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem under Xcode6 and iOS8.

However I noticed that this appears to be a emulator problem. The following code works on iOS8, but only on the device (so not on the emulator)!

```
MFMailComposeViewController *composer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
    composer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    messageContent=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bla bla"];

    [composer setSubject:@"The subject"];
    [composer setMessageBody:messageContent isHTML:NO];
    [composer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Vincent@xxxxx.com"]]];

    [composer setCcRecipients:nil];
    [composer setBccRecipients:nil];
    [composer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];

    [self presentViewController:composer animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I come with this simple solution:

```
//outlet & btns
@IBOutlet weak var forgotEmail: UITextField!

@IBAction func resetPW(sender: AnyObject) {
    // send email
    var mailer = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self
    mailer.setSubject("Forgot Password")
    mailer.setToRecipients(["admin@someMail.com"])

    presentViewController(mailer, animated:true, completion: nil)

}
```

P.S.: "setToRecipients" works on a real device only, not in the simulator !